# Difference between Request and Requests in Laravel

Tags: laravel

What is the difference between

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
```

?
Both look like same and how do their differ in working ?

Answer (score 1):

`Illuminate\Http\Request` is used in a controller to handle an incoming request (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, ...) and even more it's explained beautifully in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests).

`App\Http\Requests` is the parent namespace used for form validation rules, this allows you to keep your controller clean and write the validation rules for an incoming request in a separate class. It also makes your validation class reusable for other controllers. Again nicely documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation).